# Google colab environment/container testing in GitHub Action

Tags: google-colaboratory

I would like to test a notebook regularly with the lastest preinstalled colab environment? I found a hint that there is a docker container available:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76360314/9684872

Is there an alternative to the docker image I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

The colab docker image used for deployment can be used to test notebooks on a large GitHub runner. So, using the docker image seems the best option to ensure compatibility with the latest deployment of colab.

Needs a larger runner due to disk-space requirements. This needs "manually" adding the required large runner to a GitHub organization.

images: https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/docker/colab-images/europe/public/runtime

```yaml
name: Test that tutorial runs on latest colab image

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 2 * * 3'

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest-4core # needs to be create manually
    # https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/docker/colab-images/europe/public/runtime
    container:
      image: europe-docker.pkg.dev/colab-images/public/runtime:latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - ...
```